# Passing a Button in FXML using JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Hello I Have this portion of my code, I actually need disable the button when the user is logging, I am trying to pass the button to the FXML, but nothing happens: this is the code in `the Main Controller`, when the user is logged and data match with the password and username the button with the variable `btn1` must disabled, I post my entire code for any help.

```
public Button getBtn1() {
    return btn1;
}

public void conexion () {
    String  usus="";
    String Passu ="";
    String Bd="jdbc:sqlserver: // THUMANO2:1433;databaseName=QUORA";
    String Usuario="sa";
    String Pass="milkas87";
    String SqlQuery= "select NOMBREUSUARIO, CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), (DecryptByPassPhrase('*xc/6789oÑ---+y',PASS))) as PASS from usuarios where  CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), (DecryptByPassPhrase('*xc/6789oÑ---+y',PASS)))='"+fcontrasena.getText().toString().trim()+"'";
    Connection Conexion = null;

    try {
        Conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
        PreparedStatement ps =Conexion.prepareStatement(SqlQuery);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            usus = rs.getString("NOMBREUSUARIO");
            Passu = rs.getString("PASS"); 
        }

        if(fcontrasena.getText().toString().trim().equals(Passu) && fusuario.getText().toString().equals(usus)) {
            Stage administrador=new Stage();

            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Admin.fxml"));
                Stage login=(Stage)fusuario.getScene().getWindow();
                Parent root = loader.load();
                AdminScreenController controlador = loader.<AdminScreenController>getController();
                controlador.setBtn1(btn1);
                Scene scene=new Scene(root);
                 scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
                administrador.setScene(scene);
                administrador.setTitle("AdminScreen");
                login.hide();
                administrador.show();
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error","ERROR",0);
    }
}
```

this is the code for `AdminScreenController`:

```
public void setBtn1(Button btn1) {
    btn1.setDisable(true);
}
```

this is the FXML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="576.0" prefWidth="791.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.AdminScreenController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="bpane" prefHeight="621.0" prefWidth="791.0">
         <left>
            <VBox fx:id="vboxr" prefHeight="576.0" prefWidth="205.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="205.0">
                     <center>
                        <Button fx:id="btn1" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Planilla Sistemas" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="205.0">
                     <center>
                        <Button fx:id="btn2" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="AMP" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="205.0">
                     <center>
                        <Button fx:id="btn3" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Tareas Funcionarios" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="205.0">
                     <center>
                        <Button fx:id="btn4" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="127.0" text="Indicadores" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                     </center>
                  </BorderPane>
                  <BorderPane prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="205.0" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </left>
         <top>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="145.0" prefWidth="791.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <left>
                  <Pane fx:id="imgview" prefHeight="145.0" prefWidth="205.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
               </left>
            </BorderPane>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

its something wrong? i need some orientation here. thanks.

Comment: The button should be created in the `Controller` not the `Main`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm

Comment: @Sedrick would you give me an example please?

Comment: I gave you a link to an example. You need to do some tutorials. You have not grasped the basics yet.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginSQLiteFx

Comment: Thanks for updating your code The link above may help.

Comment: [mcve] please .. (mind the _M_ - nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows the MVC relationship in JavaFX. The button is defined in FXML and injected into the controller where it can be accessed.

**TestAppView.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.app.TestAppController">
    <Button fx:id="myButton" text="Hello World" />
</VBox>
```

**TestAppController.java**

```
public class TestAppController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button myButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Prints Hello World & disables the button when clicked
        myButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            myButton.setDisable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

**TestAppMain.java**

```
public class TestAppMain extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(TestAppController.class.getResource("TestAppView.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello Steve, how i can disable the button when the user log in, I edit the code.

Comment: Where is your button defined? Is it defined in the FXML file or Java? Can you post your FXML in the question?

Comment: Steve can we  Chat?

Comment: Please anyone to help me?  I Just need to disabling the button.